# RabbitMQ - PHP multi-consumers not working as expected

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I have a series of office files that I need to convert to PDF. I'm using an installed version of LibreOffice in my CentOS that I run as command line from PHP to do the files conversion. Since files will be uploaded by users, to convert them, I opted for a message queue system RabbitMQ.

Below is my PHP codes for creating a job, publishing it and consuming it by a worker.

database.php

```
<?php 
/*****Database Access*****/
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'my_database';
$user = 'my_user';
$pass = 'my_pass_here';
$port = "3306";
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
];
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset;port=$port";
try {
    $pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int) $e->getCode());
}
```

For publishing a job, I have a loop that sends every file location I have to the consumer (worker) side:

job_publisher.php

```
<?php

require_once '/home/myuser/myfolder/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '/home/myuser/public_html/database.php';

/*****Jobs Publisher*****/
$passive = false;
$durable = true;
$exclusive = false;
$autoDelete = false;
$nowait = false;
$arguments = null;
$ticket = null;
$exchangeType = "direct";
$exchangeName = "pdf_convert_exchange";
$queueName = "pdf_convert_queue";
$noLocal = false;
$noACK = false;

$rabbitMQConnectionObj = new \PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection(
        "localhost",
        5672,
        "user_rmq",
        "pass_rmq"
);
$rabbitMQConnectionChannelObj = $rabbitMQConnectionObj->channel();
$rabbitMQConnectionChannelObj->queue_declare(
        $queueName,
        $passive,
        $durable,
        $exclusive,
        $autoDelete,
        $nowait,
        $arguments,
        $ticket
);
$rabbitMQConnectionChannelObj->exchange_declare(
        $exchangeName,
        $exchangeType,
        $passive,
        $durable,
        $exclusive
);
$rabbitMQConnectionChannelObj->queue_bind(
       $queueName,
       $exchangeName
);

//Loop to send messages
$path = "/home/mysuer/public_html";
$files = [
    [
        "token" => random_int(1000000000, 9999999999),
        "file_convert_location" => $path."/OK_Agree.docx"
    ],
    [
        "token" => random_int(1000000000, 9999999999),
        "file_convert_location" => $path."/Accounting.xlsx"
    ],
    [
        "token" => random_int(1000000000, 9999999999),
        "file_convert_location" => $path."/Presentation.pptx"
    ],
    [
        "token" => random_int(1000000000, 9999999999),
        "file_convert_location" => $path."/Tax.docx"
    ],
    [
        "token" => random_int(1000000000, 9999999999),
        "file_convert_location" => $path."/tuto.docx"
    ],
];

foreach ($files as $fileDetails) {
    /*****Create Msg payload and publish it to workers*****/
    $token = $fileDetails["token"];
    $fileConvertLocation = $fileDetails["file_convert_location"];
    $jobArray = array(
        "token" => $token,
        "dir_output" => $path,
        "file_convert_location" => $fileConvertLocation
    );

    //Insert record to mark starting of PDF conversion process and track it by ID
    $sql = "INSERT INTO convert_files_pdf (token, file_convert_location, dir_output, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$token, $fileConvertLocation, $path, "Converting File..."]);

    //Makes message to publish persistent (2);
    $msg = new \PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage(
        json_encode($jobArray),
        array('delivery_mode' => 2)
    );

    //Send message payload to workers.
    $rabbitMQConnectionChannelObj->basic_publish($msg, $exchangeName);
}
```

When I run the job_publisher.php I can see 5 messages queued in RMQ Management interface.

worker.php

```
<?php
require_once '/home/myuser/myfolder/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '/home/myuser/public_html/database.php';

$passive = false;
$durable = true;
$exclusive = false;
$autoDelete = false;
$nowait = false;
$arguments = null;
$ticket = null;
$exchangeType = "direct";
$exchangeName = "pdf_convert_exchange";
$queueName = "pdf_convert_queue";
$noLocal = false;
$noACK = false;

$rabbitMQConnectionObj = new \PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection(
        "localhost",
        5672,
        "user_rmq",
        "pass_rmq"
);
$rabbitMQConnectionChannelObj = $rabbitMQConnectionObj->channel();
$rabbitMQConnectionChannelObj->queue_declare(
        $queueName,
        $passive,
        $durable,
        $exclusive,
        $autoDelete,
        $nowait,
        $arguments,
        $ticket
);
$rabbitMQConnectionChannelObj->exchange_declare(
        $exchangeName,
        $exchangeType,
        $passive,
        $durable,
        $exclusive
);
$rabbitMQConnectionChannelObj->queue_bind(
       $queueName,
       $exchangeName
);

$callback = function ($msg) use ($pdo){
    $job = json_decode($msg->body, true);
    $response = startPdfConversionProcess(
            $job['token'],
            $job['file_convert_location'],
            $job['dir_output'],
            $pdo
    );
    if ($response[0] === "Executed") {
        $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
    } else {
        $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_nack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
    }
};

if (!is_null($callback)) {
    $rabbitMQConnectionChannelObj->basic_qos(null, 1, null);
    $rabbitMQConnectionChannelObj->basic_consume(
            $queueName,
            "PDF_CONVERTER",
            $noLocal,
            $noACK,
            $exclusive,
            $nowait,
            $callback
    );
    while (count($rabbitMQConnectionChannelObj->callbacks)) {
        $rabbitMQConnectionChannelObj->wait();
    }
}

function startPdfConversionProcess(string $token, string $fileConvertLocation, string $dirOut, \PDO $pdo) {
    try {
        $output = shell_exec('libreoffice --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export "' . $fileConvertLocation . '" --outdir "' . $dirOut . '" --headless');
        $status = "Excecuted";
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $output = $e->getMessage();
        $status = "Failed";
    }
    //Update record to mark end of PDF conversion process track it by ID
    $sql = "UPDATE convert_files_pdf SET status = ?, log = ? WHERE token = ?";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$status, $output, $token]);
    return [$status, $output];
}
```

When I run 1 worker only, jobs are consumed one by one and everything works fine and I can see the logs saved in my table see capture One below (some jobs are Unacked but they are put in the queue again and reprocessed automatically).

[image: One consumer only]

When I run 10 workers using the command `php worker.php &` 10 times and leave them waiting for jobs, then run the jobs publisher, It seems that only few workers run and the rest of the workers put jobs in the Unacked status and it stays like that see capture below. Also, it seems that the logs are never saved when multiple workers are receiving jobs.

[image: 10 workers run]

1. Why logs are not caught in case of many workers? Does it have to do with `shell_exec`?
2. Since one worker alone worked fine I was expecting that many workers will each receive a job and process it which will speed up the conversion rather than using only one. Am I wrong in my PHP code or in the way this RabbitMQ is supposed to work when you run multiple consumers listening to the same queue on the same channel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone reading this post, the code logic above is working fine, the issue was with this command `libreoffice --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export "' . $fileConvertLocation . '" --outdir "' . $dirOut . '" --headless` It turned out that libreoffice does not handle well concurrent requests. I had to change the command as following to start a libreoffice process for every PHP request made:

```
libreoffice -env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/delete_me_{$uniqueIdHere} --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export "' . $fileConvertLocation . '" --outdir "' . $dirOut . '" --headless 2>&1
```

If someone can explain in RabbitMQ what to do when a message in nacked, that may complete this question.
Thanks.